# Why Laravel accessor fires on insert?

Tags: laravel, accessor

I'm not sure how they work, I was thinking that accessor fires when you access the attribute, however when I try to insert new record my accessor fires. I store in my database only image_name by removing URL and I use an accessor to include my URL route when I retrieve my image name. I found out that my accessor fires on insert and change my input:

## ImageRepository.php

```
public function save($imageData)
{
    $this->model->owner()->associate(auth()->user());
    $this->model->type       = $imageData->type;
    $this->model->image_name = $imageData->image_url;
    $this->model->save();

    return $this->model;
}
```

## Image.php

```
public function getImageNameAttribute($value)
{
    $filePath = 'my_path';

    // check if method was hit
    logger()->info('getImageNameAttribute: '.$value);

    // return default image if not found
    if ($value == '' || $value == null || Str::contains($value, 'no-image.png') || !File::exists(public_path($filePath))) {
        return asset('img/no-image.png');
    } else {
        return asset($filePath);
    }
}
```

Input for `$imageData->image_url`:
https://some-random-image-url/image-name.jpg

Inserted data:
img/no-image.png

Excepted output (I have a function that extracts the name from URL):
image-name.jpg

When I check the log, I get the message:

> getImageNameAttribute: https://some-random-image-url/image-name.jpg

Can someone explain to me if I'm doing something wrong or this is working as pretended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the problem, I miss checked. Actually inserted record in my database is correct:

```
image-name.jpg
```

But I was checking `dd()` output after the insert and the value from there was not correct:

```
img/no-image.png
```

Because when `dd()` fires, the accessor is also fired (as we are retrieving data) and as the image was not downloaded it was actually showing correct data.